# Turn Excel line break into <br>

Tags: excel

A client sent me a huge list of product name and descriptions. The Description cells have text wrap and many line breaks. I need to import this into a MySQL which I do through Navicat Premium.

The problem is that the description cell is used as the HTML description of each product page.

Is there a way to replace Excel's line break with the `<br>` either in the same Excel file or by a php function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A little bit of ASCII coding will go a long way.

Set up the find/replace dialogue (Ctrl-H). In the Find field, hold down the Alt key and type 010 from the numeric key pad. (This lets you find a linefeed character.) In the replace field, put your `<br>`.

Comment: @EriF89 - In Excel's F&R you can also use `Ctrl+J` to get a linefeed (`vbLF`) character.

Answer (score 5):

or use a VBA function to replace the carriage returns in a string

Insert a MODULE and paste this

```
Function LineFeedReplace(ByVal str As String)
dim strReplace as String

strReplace = "<br>"

LineFeedReplace = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(str, Chr(10), strReplace), Chr(13), strReplace), vbCr , strReplace), vbCrLf, strReplace), vbLf, strReplace), vbNewLine, strReplace)

End Function
```

If cell A1 contains a string with a linefeed then `=LineFeedReplace(A1)` will return the string with all linefeeds set to `<br>`

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you account for both CR and LF which tend to come together. The codes for these are 0013 and 0010 and so you will need a formula that allows you to clean both. I used this formula successfully `=SUBSTITUTE(A3,CHAR(13),"<br>")` to convert a cell of long text in excel replacing invisible breaks with the `'br'` tag. Since you can't tell exactly what kind of line break you have you can also try it with 0010  or `=SUBSTITUTE(A3,CHAR(10),"<br>")`