# Substitute a comma with a line break in a cell

Tags: excel

In the cell below, I want to get whatever is separated by a comma to come to a new line. I can add these line breaks manually with alt+enter, but this time I want to automate it.

> BCM:Open,Event:Site XXXX is down,Service Affected :2G,Impact :Coverage
>   Restored at XXXX Area,Reason:Under Investigation,Recovery Time :30
>   Minutes,Start time:14:25:13,End Time:15:18:03,Duration:00:52:50,SLA:1
>   Hour.

Comment: Does the cell contain the actual text "XXXX" or is that just an example value?

Comment: @user Share file via dropbox or any similar service

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6116403/509840.

Answer (score 127):

For some reason, none of the above worked for me. This DID however:

1. Selected the range of cells I needed to replace.
2. Go to <kbd>Home > Find & Select > Replace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
3. Find what: `,`
4. Replace with: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
5. Click `Replace All`

Somehow <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> is registered as a linebreak.

Comment: In general, since people may have remapped ` <CTRL><SHIFT>J` or other versions of Excel may kill that,  you can hold down the `<ALT>` key and type 0010 on the numeric keypad to access the actual ascii char

Answer (score 43):

To replace commas with newline characters use this formula (assuming that the text to be altered is in cell A1):

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",CHAR(10))`

You may have to then alter the row height to see all of the values in the cell

I've left a comment about the other part of your question

---

Edit: here's a screenshot of this working - **I had to turn on "Wrap Text"** in the "Format Cells" dialog.

[image: A screenshot of an Excel worksheet with the text a,b,c,d,e,f in cell A1. Cell B1 is selected and the formula bar shows =SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",CHAR(10)). Row 1 is expanded in height and the contents of cell B1 show one letter per line with the text a b c d e f]

Comment: Not really - this still be visible in Excel as string without line breaks... I think that's not OP wants.

Comment: Wrap text makes the difference, however that's not obvious. Nevertheless, this works.

Comment: This not only works for Excel, but for Quip as well (and possibly other excel derivatives like Google sheets - havent tried though)

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",CHAR(10) & CHAR(13))
```

This will replace each comma with a new line. Change `A1` to the cell you are referencing.

Comment: CHAR(10) is LF (line feed) and CHAR(13) is CR (carriage return). Usually they are in the order CR LF. Are you sure that your formula works?

Comment: Make sure you have word wrap turned on!

Comment: @PaoloGibellini, You are right, the formula should be `SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",CHAR(13) & CHAR(10))`, to work perfectly. if we put 10 then 13, it will have an additional empty line.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this without VBA from the find/replace dialogue box. My answer was at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116681/509840 .

Answer (score 0):

Windows (unlike some other OS's, like Linux), uses CR+LF for line breaks:

- CR = 13 = 0x0D = ^M = \r = carriage return
- LF = 10 = 0x0A = ^J = \n = new line

The characters need to be in that order, if you want the line breaks to be consistently visible when copied to other Windows programs.  So the Excel function would be:

=SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",CHAR(13) & CHAR(10))