# Split single line cell into mulitline cell using delimeter in a Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of data nearly 500 cells of data in the below image format. Please help me out by giving some suggestions.

[image: Single lined cell to multiline cell using delimeter]

P.S: I am a beginner in Excel Vba

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856501/substitute-a-comma-with-a-break-link-in-a-cell) use the macro recorder to follow your steps and then modify the resultant code to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before:

[image]

The code:

```
Sub FixThisSheet()
    Cells.Replace What:=";", replacement:=Chr(10)
    Cells.WrapText = True
End Sub
```

After:

[image]