# Replace inline breaks with new lines excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a heap of poorly formatted Excel sheets
All the data is in one cell with `alt+"enter"` inline breaks between the lines.
I would like all the values on different lines. 
I was thinking of doing a find-and-replace search for `"alt+010"` 
What do I replace it with?
Can this be achieved in VBA

Similar question here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116403/turn-excel-line-break-into-br/6116681#6116681)

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Hi @mehow. My attempt at the problem is to do a find-and-replace search for "alt+010" but I don't know what to replace it with. I have endlessly googled the Acsii code for `enter` but the closest I have found is the enter symbol

Comment: there are VBA constants like `vbNewLine` or `VbCrLf` which are break lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done as a two step process

1. Text to Column - use Delimites, Other, Ascii code 10  (`Alt` `0010` on the  numeric keypad)
2. Copy, Paste Special, Transpose

Comment: Perfect. That Text to Column did the trick. I'll be able to figure the VBA out from here