# What is the character code for new line break in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, line-breaks

I tried `char(10)` and `char(13)` but they don`t work by me. I use Excel 2007 and my task  is to replace new lines with intervals

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn Excel line break into <br>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116403/turn-excel-line-break-into-br)

Comment: No it doesnt work. It doesn`t find me Alt  + 010, neither Alt + 013, neither 0010, nor 0013, NOR CTRL + J. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please try Alt + 0010.

Comment: Nope, is it a setting from somewhere?

Comment: The solution from [Turn Excel line break into <br>](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6116403/1652222) worked for me. Provide some more details what exactly you are trying

Comment: I try to replace new lines with an interval. I tried everything: from standart dialog box I try to replace Alt + all posible combinations, but it doesn`t work

Comment: One thing I found is that sometimes when I do not do it on the first try that I do not clear everything in the find box.  Make sure everything is deleted from the box, you will not see anything but it might still have an invisible character.  Then hit only ctrl - j, it will appear empty. but it is there.

Comment: What is an interval?

Comment: empty space, for instance

Comment: If you're trying CTRL+J, you should be able to use `ALT+ENTER`. But you're asking for the character, so maybe that's not helpful...A note also, if you are using `CHAR(10)` (and probably other options), make sure Text wrapping is turned on for that cell.  Otherwise you won't see the line break.

Comment: Wait - you're trying to *replace* new line breaks.  Does this not work? `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," ")` . Where `A1` is a cell with text, and line breaks? If not, can you please show us the data, what's it look like?

Comment: This comment should be in the answer tab.. (:

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use CHAR(10) and **Turn on Wrap Text** option. It should work.

Comment: This is OS-dependent. CHAR(10) for Windows and CHAR(13) for Mac.

Comment: unfortunetely it doesn't.

Comment: CHAR(10) works if you enable word wrap for the cell

Comment: @HendraAnggrian You can use `CHAR(10)&CHAR(13)` if you need to make sure it works on both

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Alt] + [Enter] key. This will create a new line feed in the cell.